# HTTP 400 Bad Request on REST request using Spring Mvc

Tags: java, spring, rest

When I call my REST "Hello world" server, I get an http response 400 Bad Request.

My application works with Spring like a MVC application.

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);


    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String getHello(@RequestParam("request") String json,
            HttpServletRequest request) {

        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

Here's my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here's my root-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

</beans>
```

Here's my servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />    
    <context:component-scan base-package="uk.co.dango" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txnManager"/>

    <context:annotation-config />

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <mvc:view-controller path="/index" view-name="home"/>

</beans>
```

I make the request with a Rest client from Firefox, calling the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/dango/hello
```

This is the body:

```
request={"test"=1}
```

This is the content-type:

```
content-type=application/x-javascript
```

If I change anything in the URL I get Http 404, so I know that the URL is correct at least. Indeed I receive Http 400. But what I can do to fix this?

Comment: What do you expect the request body to map to and why?

Comment: Your controller is expecting a request to `/hello` with `request=someParam` as the body. That's what @RequestParam means.

Comment: request can be any string, because I just expect the controller to answer "Hello World"

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've seen that after. But still, it expects a valid POST form parameter. Not JSON.

Comment: ok, it happens even if I write "request=blabla"

Comment: And what if you remove this encoding and use the proper application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you expect to happen. This

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String getHello(@RequestParam("request") String json,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
```

A `@RequestParam` requires a request parameter. A request parameter is defined as as URL query string element or an element in a form submission.

You're sending

```
POST http://localhost:8080/dango/hello
content-type=application/x-javascript

request={"test"=1}
```

which neither has a form submission nor a query string. Since `@RequestParam`'s `required` attribute is set to `true` by default, Spring responds with a 400 Bad Request (it can't find a value to provide for it).

As [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702483/http-400-bad-request-on-rest-request-using-spring-mvc/26702636#comment41998482_26702483) has suggested, change your content type to

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

to indicate form submission. Or pass the parameter in query string

```
http://localhost:8080/dango/hello?request=something
```

You may also want to look into `@RequestBody`.